# How to have css hover effect affect child elements differently?

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a rectangular div with 2 components in it. An Image element and a div of text under that. I would like to do a hover effect on the whole div that affects the two child components in different ways.

For example I would like for the image to have a different brightness, and the text to have a different background-color and text color (but unchanged brightness).

Here is a fiddle of a skeleton (a main div containing 2 child divs), but the css is not what I want.
https://jsfiddle.net/jhbf5c9n/

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
<!--  this div should have decrease in brightness -->
  <div class="effect1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
  </div>
<!-- this div should have constant 100% brightness, but background color and font color should change -->
  <div class="effect2">
    <p>This div should change background</p>  
    <p>And font color</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p{
  margin: 0;
}
div.main-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
div.effect1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
div.effect2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
div.main-container:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

The main goal is to have a single hover event trigger css differently for different child elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do some hover effect on div which changes something in its child then you could do this

```
 .main-container:hover > .effect1 > img {
      -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
 }

 .main-container:hover > .effect2 > p{
     background-color: blue;
     color: white;
 }
```

This will change the brightness of image in effect1 and text in effect2 on single hover. Hope that's your answer

Answer (score 2):

In your fiddle you could use following code to get desired result:

```
div.main-container:hover .effect1 {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(10%);
}
```

Simlarly you can do for other child also.